# Change public_path() in Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel

I can't change `public_path()` in laravel 10.
Here is my code in `index.php`

```
$app = require_once __DIR__ . '/../../../File Web/mmteknik/bootstrap/app.php';
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
   return __DIR__;
});
```

and `public_path` still returns

```
/home/u15xxxx/File Web/mmteknik/public
```

It should return

```
/home/u15xxxx/public_html/subdomain/mmteknik/public
```

Can anyone can help me? Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 10 you need to use

```
app()->usePublicPath(__DIR__.'/public');
```

method offered by

> Illuminate\Foundation\Application

object

find more at [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/upgrade#public-path-binding)